# Data is lost when app is closed

Tags: android

I want the user to enter some data and i store it in a variable so as to be later displayed. But when the app is opened the next time the previously entered data is lost. What do I do?

Comment: Use SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Please, read at first [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)

Comment: Variables will be reset every time you launch the application so you should persist data ! Use sharedpreferences

Comment: Please do proper research before answering a question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      String MyPREFERENCES=this.getPackageName();
      sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      //your rest code here
    }

    //write data
    private void storeUserData(String val1){

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("uName", val1);
        editor.commit();
    }

    //read data
    private String read userData(){
        return this.sharedpreferences.getString("uName", "");
    }
```